# Azure Bicep - Cross resource group reference using Scope

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

In my Azure Bicep deployment, I am deploying on to a resource group (RG2) trying to refer Azure resources (eg: Service Bus) from another resource group (RG1) using the "scope" property.

eg:

```
  name: resourceNames.storageAccountName  
  scope: resourceGroup(resourceNames.coreRG)
}
```

Whenever I am using scope, it gives me an error:

`"The client 'xx@yyy.org' with object id 'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/read' over scope '/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/yyyy/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/zzzz' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."`

However, if i remove the scope and deploy everything to the same resourcegroup (RG1) it works successfully.

I am trying it on my personal subscription to rule out any permissions issues.
I have the following permission :
**Service Administrator** : *Has full access to all resources in the subscription*

I even added "**Contributor**" to RG1 as an add-on but it did not help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think providing your sample bicep files will be more helpful

Comment: Owner or Contributor role at the subscription level will give you full access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have "**Contributor**" permissions on both Resource Groups.

As simple and silly as it seems, the issue was due to a **wrong Resource Group name** (missed out a suffix).

The error was not very helpful and I suppose its more inclined to this part of the error message:  **or the scope is invalid**

Thanks all for your help !

Answer (score 1):

> "The client 'xx@yyy.org' with object id 'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/read' over scope " xx"

This error occurs when you have lack of permissions to access or retrieve the resources from resource groups.

Firstly, make sure that you have `read` permissions on resource group (RG1) according to the error `Microsoft.Web/sites/read`.

And you need to have `Contributor` permissions on resource group (RG2) to deploy the resources into it.

`Contributor` is the at least role you need to provide for both resource groups in this scenario.

Add a `reader` role to the RG1 using Azure Portal or below CLI command.
[`az role  assignment create --role`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-assignment-create-examples) .

```bash
az role assignment create --assignee xxxx.onmicrosoft.com --role Reader --scope ""
```

[image]

Or as @Thomas suggested, `Owner` or `Contributor` role at the subscription level will give you full access without any restrictions.